# How to do expand and collapse for table column in html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one HTML (with CSS )file. It has details about progress bar Logs.

In the table, see the start date cloumn. The start date for progress id is mostly same. Consider like the start date is 23-12-2014 09:20:30  for 20 process id.. I have to display only one process id in the date 23-12-2014 09:20:30 instead of displaying 20 records. if i click this then remaining 19 records should expand and display..

i knew about collapsein in javascript.. But don't know how to implement here.

Am newer for Javascript..Help me ..!!

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #343131">
    <p class="header">Progress Logs</p>
    <table class="table1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">Process Id</th><th scope="col">Start Time</th><th scope="col">End Time</th><th scope="col">Output Type</th><th scope="col">Input File Count</th><th scope="col">Processed file Count</th><th scope="col">No of Accounts</th><th scope="col">No of Processed Accounts</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Progress&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th scope="col"></th><th scope="col" style="text-align:left;">Status</th><th scope="col">Failed File Count</th><th scope="col">Summary</th><th scope="col">Error Log</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">17438@sdrtbp01</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;12:47:38</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;12:50:04</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">pdf</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="javascript:window.alert('[exp_2_229436_1_m3] ');">1</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">1</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">566</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">566</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">
    <hr class="progress" style="width:100%;color:#2f2;">
    </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right;color:#2f2;">100.00%</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;;color:#2f2;">Finished Successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;" align="center">0</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">All the files processed successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="20141223124738_17438@sdrtbp01.xml">
                    View
                </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">17079@sdrtbp01</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;12:08:09</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;12:10:37</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">pdf</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="javascript:window.alert('[exp_2_229436_1_m3] ');">1</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">1</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">566</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">566</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">
    <hr class="progress" style="width:100%;color:#2f2;">
    </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right;color:#2f2;">100.00%</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;;color:#2f2;">Finished Successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;" align="center">0</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">All the files processed successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="20141223120809_17079@sdrtbp01.xml">
                    View
                </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">16966@sdrtbp01</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;11:58:23</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;12:04:47</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">ps</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="javascript:window.alert('[cmsr_2_20140306_1.dat] ');">1</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">1</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">1697</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">1697</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">
    <hr class="progress" style="width:100%;color:#2f2;">
    </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right;color:#2f2;">100.00%</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;;color:#2f2;">Finished Successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;" align="center">0</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">All the files processed successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="20141223115823_16966@sdrtbp01.xml">
                    View
                </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">16866@sdrtbp01</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;11:50:03</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;11:52:55</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">ps</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="javascript:window.alert('[exp_2_229436_1_m3] ');">1</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">1</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">566</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">566</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">
    <hr class="progress" style="width:100%;color:#2f2;">
    </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right;color:#2f2;">100.00%</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;;color:#2f2;">Finished Successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;" align="center">0</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">All the files processed successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="20141223115003_16866@sdrtbp01.xml">
                    View
                </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">16868@sdrtbp01</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;11:50:02</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;11:50:44</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">ps</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="javascript:window.alert('[exp_2_234215_1_m15] ');">1</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">1</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">31</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">31</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">
    <hr class="progress" style="width:100%;color:#2f2;">
    </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right;color:#2f2;">100.00%</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;;color:#2f2;">Finished Successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;" align="center">0</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">All the files processed successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="20141223115002_16868@sdrtbp01.xml">
                    View
                </a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">15589@sdrtbp01</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;09:20:30</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;09:21:09</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="javascript:window.alert('');">8</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">8</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">8</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">8</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">
    <hr class="progress" style="width:100%;color:#2f2;">
    </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right;color:#2f2;">100.00%</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;;color:#2f2;">Finished Successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;" align="center">0</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">All the files processed successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="20141223092030_15589@sdrtbp01.xml">
                    View
                </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">15581@sdrtbp01</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;09:20:30</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;09:21:09</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="javascript:window.alert('');">5</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">5</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">9</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">9</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">
    <hr class="progress" style="width:100%;color:#2f2;">
    </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right;color:#2f2;">100.00%</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;;color:#2f2;">Finished Successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;" align="center">0</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">All the files processed successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="20141223092030_15581@sdrtbp01.xml">
                    View
                </a></td>
    </tr>
    </details>
    <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">15578@sdrtbp01</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;09:20:30</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;09:21:07</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="javascript:window.alert('');">4</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">4</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">6</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">6</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">
    <hr class="progress" style="width:100%;color:#2f2;">
    </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right;color:#2f2;">100.00%</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;;color:#2f2;">Finished Successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;" align="center">0</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">All the files processed successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="20141223092030_15578@sdrtbp01.xml">
                    View
                </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">15574@sdrtbp01</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;09:20:30</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">23-12-2014&nbsp;09:21:07</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="javascript:window.alert('');">2</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">2</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">2</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">2</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">
    <hr class="progress" style="width:100%;color:#2f2;">
    </td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right;color:#2f2;">100.00%</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;;color:#2f2;">Finished Successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;" align="center">0</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;">All the files processed successfully</td><td style="white-space:nowrap;color:#2f2;"><a href="20141223092030_15574@sdrtbp01.xml">
                    View
                </a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is an [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). Accordion is a UI design and is available in many major libraries. It will take quite some effort if you want to build it from scratch in native JS. I would suggest you to use a library for this.

In this case the first record out of the 20 record group will be the section header. By default the section header will be collapsed and when clicked it will expand and show rest 19 records.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you would like to accomplish but I took a stab at it. Is this what you're looking for?

CSS

```
tbody tr{
  display: none;
}

tbody tr:first-child{
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
$("tbody tr:first").click(function(){
  $("tbody tr").show();   
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5oyuzhrc/)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. No need of CSS. Need javascript function. In my file many process id has same start time. Instead of Displaying all it should display only one record. if i click the record it should expand and show the process details which has the same start time.

Comment: so is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No. Need in javascript.. In the above table, the start date column should be collapse and expand. i don't know to do this.

Comment: that is javascript, the part that says "JS"

Answer (score 0):

How i worked with Expand and collapse functionality is, with the help of JS.

```
<td id="<ExpandImage>">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:expandAll();">
          <img src="image<forClick>"/>
   </a>
</td>

function expand()
{
    document.getElementById('<ExpandTab>').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('<CollapseTab>').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('<ExpandImage>').innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:collapse();"><img src="images<collapse>"/></a>';
}

function collapse()
{
    document.getElementById('<ExpandTab>').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('<CollapseTab>').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('<ExpandImage>').innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:expand();"><img src="images<Expand>" /></a>';
}
```